# vector spin last content into the beginning

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a vector with element and I want to spin them around, basically I want to take the last x elements and push it to the beginning of the vector:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
```

Here is my current implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int size = 9;
    std::vector<int> vec(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        vec[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << vec[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int spinCount = 6;
    for(int i = 0; i < spinCount; i++)
    {
        int last = vec[size - 1];
        for(int j = size - 1; j > 0; j--)
        {
            int num = vec[j - 1];
            vec[j] = num;
        }
        vec[0] = last;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << vec[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

But it has a loop inside a loop, making it a square complexity. Is there a way to make it more efficient?

Comment: You might want to put this on the code review site. Also, do you need to use a vector? This would be very easy with a doubly linked list

Comment: Yakk's answer gives you a solution, but does not provide explanation. So, if you need to do the same for a given data-structure, but there is no library function, then you will not be able to implement a quick solution. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::rotate( begin(vec), begin(vec)+3, end(vec) );
```

rotates a `vec` by 3 spots so that the first 3 elements are now at the end.

Comment: Your solution solves the problem, but the op had a solution as well. The problem was that he considered his solution too complex and intended to implement a quicker solution. Your answer does not describe what happens. It is nice to suggest library functions, but you should also describe what happens there and why is it quicker than op's solution.

Comment: @LajosArpad the rotate is exactly what I was looking for, and it's also linear complexity!

Comment: Then it is all right. I thought you wanted to implement the algorithm and I did not consider std::rotate the best from the educational point of view, as the algorithm is hidden. I believe you should try to implement this yourself, you need to get some experience and to solve some problems yourself to become a professional. As about Yakk's solution: it is absolutely correct and it addresses the problem. But did you understand what was the solution to your problem from this answer? No.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fighting against what vector was designed for use `std::deque`. It has `push_front` method you can use without manually coded loops.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm in my answer makes as many shifts as the size of the `vector`. It is a recursive algorithm. Let me describe it to you in words:

First of all, you need to check whether `currentIndex` is out of the bounds of the `vector`. If so, then the rotation ends for the given `value`. Then, we have to know how much elements need a new value after we save the `value` of a current spin, `spinCount` is the number of elements to be spinned. If `vec` still has enough room for a full shift, then we trigger a new shift on the new index. If there is not enough room for a full shift, then we shift by the amount needed. Finally, we save the value at `currentIndex`.

```
void rotateMyVector(std::vector<int> &vec, int size, int currentIndex, int spinCount, spinIndex, int value) {
    if (currentIndex >= size) {
        return;
    }
    int amount = size - currentIndex + spinIndex - spinCount;
    if (amount >= spinCount) {
        rotateMyVector(vec, size, currentIndex + spinCount, spinIndex, vec[currentIndex]);
    } else {
        vec[currentIndex + amount] = vec[currentIndex];
    }
    vec[currentIndex] = value;
}
```

Then we have to call the function at the appropriate place in the code:

```
for (int index = size - spinCount; index < size; index++) {
    rotateMyVector(vec, size, index - (size - spinCount), index - (size - spinCount), vec[index]);
}
```

Note, that this algorithm was not tested, please, tell me if I have made a typo anywhere.

Comment: What is the complexity of that recursion?

Comment: If we take the size of the vector as input, then it is linear, as it moves spinCount number of elements size/spinCount times. I believe std::rotate is either implemented this way or by the creation of another vector of the same size where you copy an element on a given index to the ((index + spinCount) % size) position. There are several possible solutions. The one in the answer is more beautiful than the one in this comment in my opinion, but it was not tested, so typos might be present.

Comment: Here is the implementation of rotate: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/

Comment: moving spinCount number of elements size/spinCount times is a square complexity

Comment: spinCount * size / spinCount = size. Do you agree?

Comment: @Vladp Or, to put it simply, you state that it has an O(m * n) complexity. But m = size / spinCount and n = spinCount. m * n = (size / spinCount) * (spinCount) = size. Therefore O(m * n) = O(size), which is linear complexity. This is proof. If you do not agree, show my mistake ;)

Comment: sorry I didn't full read what I was quoting. I thought to myself you wrote (size - spinCount) instead of the actual (size / spinCount)